# Vast Difference In Query Execution Using Identical Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

I'm not a DBA, so I will try to explain this as best as I can.  We are trying to figure out why some queries seem to execute super quick and other times not.  The query itself does not vary, nor does the plan detail vary between the two Plan Ids below, down to the % Costs on each node.  We have tried in the past to Force the better plan, but due to Stats updates and such the "schema" thinks it changed and often throws out the Forced Plan that previously worked, although we are still investigating whether Forcing these plans are solving the problem in the short term or not.

It seems strange, it's like SQL Server is toggling back and forth between the 2 plans randomly throughout the day when you would think it would stop using the longer running one, even though we cannot figure out what is ACTUALLY different about the 2 plans, other than the execution time.

Link to [Query Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hk1xVA7eI), a WinMerge XML compare between the two plan XMLs showed they are indeed identical.

We are using SQL Server 2017 RTM CU14, more details on version or config can be provided on request or need.

[image: Query Store Plan]

Comment: We would need to execution plans. You can post them here. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Updating stats shouldn't cause issues with plan forcing. Maybe something to do with it using a cursor. yep, you cant force plans with cursors in that edition. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187271/3690

Comment: are you sure the slow plans aren't populating the work table and the fast  ones selecting from it? In the graph they seem paired

Comment: @SeanLange I updated the post to include a link to the query plan.  I didn't provide both because a WinMerge compare showed the 2 XMLs were indeed identical.

Comment: I imagine the population query is the slow one and then when you get that out the way the fetch is quite fast. So the grey dots in the graph you are paying for the population and the green dots are just fetching from the cursor work table

Comment: @MartinSmith Wouldn't the plan show that difference in that case?

Comment: Also, I should mention that the reason why there is an hour gap between each node is because that's when our Stats are updated, so this graph doesn't show when something was executed, but instead a summation of it's execution history every hour.

Comment: RE: "wouldn't the plan show this?" I don't spend much time looking at cursor plans and aren't in a position to test this but as the execution plan is combined population and fetch It would make sense that first execution will be slower and subsequent fetches faster and it will show you the same plan for subsequent fetches

Comment: I would start by using ANSI-92 style joins. They are close to 30 years old now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Then use aliases with some kind of meaning. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 And last but not least if at all possible stop using cursors. Also I would get rid of the index and query hints. Those should be used as a last resort when you have exhausted everything else.

Comment: We are using a Dynamics AX 4.0 service, which has ALL the control over which method it performs joins, uses cursors, adds index hints, etc. We do have the control to override it with different index hints, but no control over removing it entirely. We've only been adding hints where we've noticed the system is issuing a bad hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer "per se", more like an extended comment.

The plan is not "complex", it is quite simple and it appears to be the best you can get (excluding the cursor). 
Two clustered tables, seeked & merge joined, aggregated for the sum()s and dumped into a clustered table in tempdb to be traversed by the cursor.
The two major points (performance wise) appear to be:

> 1. the obvious clustered index insert (writing 1.3mil rows)
> 2. the sort operator, before the stream aggregate. this most likely spills in tempdb for sorting (1.3 mil rows) . You could verify that by
>      checking an actual execution plan.

A "not so direct" observation is the number of rows: 1.3 mil before the aggregation and 1.3 mil after the aggregation. A guesstimate would be that the aggregation is not actually an aggregation for calculating sums (sum() is meaningless{?}) but more like a "distinct type" of aggregation (using sum because inventsum colums are numeric). Even the distinct aggregation might not be needed here, and you could verify that, by checking if the values of ITEMID (of the INVENTSUM table) are actually unique. If the values are not unique, then check if ITEMID is unique per AREAID&INVENTDIMID (i.e an item can appear only once for an area&invent{ory}). If either is true then, for the specific query, the ITEMID can be considered unique and as a result the aggregation (GROUP BY cols...) is not needed at all.

In theory, if ITEMID were "unique" and micro-optimization of the specific query was the goal, then a "better" execution could be achieved by clustering INVENTSUM by AREAID,INVENTDIMID, ITEMID

```
[create unique clustered index inventsumclidx on INVENTSUM(AREAID,INVENTDIMID, ITEMID)]
```

and selecting group by ITEMID, INVENTDIMID

```
GROUP BY A.ITEMID, A.INVENTDIMID, B.CONFIGID, B.INVENTSIZEID ....
ORDER BY A.ITEMID, A.INVENTDIMID, B.CONFIGID,..
```

this would eliminate the sort operator before the merge (all info is already sorted by INVENTDIMID) and the aggregation operator (all info is unique). Without spilling to tempdb for the sort before the SEGMENT a reduction of 50% in execution time could be possible.

if you have a test instance available, you could try it and check if there is any difference:

```
--drop existing clustered index 
--drop index [I_174ITEMDIMIDX] on dbo.[INVENTSUM]
create unique clustered index inventsumclidx on INVENTSUM(AREAID,INVENTDIMID, ITEMID);
go
--adjust these values
declare @P1 int = 20, @P2 int = 50, @P3 int = 15, @P4 int = 500;

declare cur cursor FAST_FORWARD for 

SELECT 
SUM(A.POSTEDQTY),SUM(A.POSTEDVALUE),SUM(A.PHYSICALVALUE),SUM(A.DEDUCTED),SUM(A.REGISTERED),SUM(A.RECEIVED),SUM(A.PICKED),SUM(A.RESERVPHYSICAL),SUM(A.RESERVORDERED),SUM(A.ONORDER),SUM(A.ORDERED),SUM(A.ARRIVED),SUM(A.QUOTATIONRECEIPT),SUM(A.QUOTATIONISSUE),SUM(A.PHYSICALINVENT),SUM(A.JSPOTENCIES),SUM(A.JSPOTENCIES2_),SUM(A.JSPOSTEDDUALUNITQTY),SUM(A.JSPICKEDDUALUNITQTY),SUM(A.JSRECEIVEDDUALUNITQTY),SUM(A.JSDEDUCTEDDUALUNITQTY),SUM(A.JSREGISTEREDDUALUNITQTY),SUM(A.AVAILPHYSICAL),SUM(A.AVAILORDERED),A.ITEMID,B.CONFIGID,B.INVENTSIZEID,B.INVENTCOLORID,B.INVENTLOCATIONID,B.WMSLOCATIONID 
FROM INVENTSUM A, INVENTDIM B WITH(INDEX(I_698DIMIDIDX)) 
WHERE ((A.DATAAREAID=@P1) AND ((A.CLOSED=@P2) AND (A.CLOSEDQTY=@P3))) AND ((B.DATAAREAID=@P4) AND (A.INVENTDIMID=B.INVENTDIMID)) 
GROUP BY A.ITEMID, A.INVENTDIMID, B.CONFIGID,B.INVENTSIZEID,B.INVENTCOLORID,B.INVENTLOCATIONID,B.WMSLOCATIONID 
ORDER BY A.ITEMID, A.INVENTDIMID, B.CONFIGID,B.INVENTSIZEID,B.INVENTCOLORID,B.INVENTLOCATIONID,B.WMSLOCATIONID
OPTION(FAST 1);

open cur;
fetch next from cur;

close cur;
deallocate cur;
```